# Call javascript function from typescript in ionic project

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I added a plugin in my ionic project, so I have the java code and the JS code like this :

```
cordova.define("cordova-sms-plugin.Sms", function(require, exports, module) {
'use strict';

var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var sms = {};

function convertPhoneToArray(phone) {
    if (typeof phone === 'string' && phone.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
        phone = phone.split(',');
    }
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(phone) !== '[object Array]') {
        phone = [phone];
    }
    return phone;
}


sms.send = function(phone, message, filename, options, success, failure) {
    // parsing phone numbers
    phone = convertPhoneToArray(phone);

    // parsing options
    var replaceLineBreaks = false;
    var androidIntent = '';
    if (typeof options === 'string') { // ensuring backward compatibility
        window.console.warn('[DEPRECATED] Passing a string as a third argument is deprecated. Please refer to the documentation to pass the right parameter: https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.');
        androidIntent = options;
    }
    else if (typeof options === 'object') {
        replaceLineBreaks = options.replaceLineBreaks || false;
        if (options.android && typeof options.android === 'object') {
            androidIntent = options.android.intent;
        }
    }

    // fire
    exec(
        success,
        failure,
        'Sms',
        'send', [phone, message, filename, androidIntent, replaceLineBreaks]
    );
};

sms.hasPermission = function(success, failure) {
    // fire
    exec(
        success,
        failure,
        'Sms',
        'has_permission', []
    );
};

module.exports = sms;
});
```

And I want to call the `sms.send(...)`  function in my Typescript code.
I tried to import file like this :

```
import sms from '../../../plugins/cordova-sms-plugin/www/sms.js';
```

or

```
import * as Sms from '../../../plugins/cordova-sms-plugin/www/sms.js';
```

or

```
window['window']['sms']['send'](...)
```

but nothing work, ionic doesn't find the `send()` function, can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling in a correct way.In your `ts` file do not need to import `js` file.

Either you can call directly by using global scope variable or you can create a `.d.ts` definition file for this plugin interface and can import on your `.ts` file.
After make sure that your plugin is installed correctly,Follow the below steps to call `cordova-sms-plugin` from `TS` file

**Step-1.** You can refer `JS variable` using `windows object` so declare it in `.ts` file

```
declare var window: any;
```

**Step-2.** Now you can call it like `window.sms.send`

```
 let phone: string;
//Set the value of phone
let message: string;
//Set the value of message
let options  = {
            "replaceLineBreaks: false"
            //
        };
 //Call the function
 window.sms.send(phone,message,options,(result: any) => {
            console.log("SuccessFully Done...");
        }, (err: any) => {
            console.log("An error has occuered :" + err.code);
        })
```

I also found a sample project on GitHub for you.You can refer this for look into the code:

https://github.com/abritopach/ionic-receiver-sms

Comment: Thank, I tried but I have an error :
 07-13 13:17:34.643 30659-30659/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: ng:///AppModule/PhotoPage.ngfactory.js: Line 96 : ERROR
07-13 13:17:34.643 30659-30659/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(96)] "ERROR", source: ng:///AppModule/PhotoPage.ngfactory.js (96)
07-13 13:17:34.646 30659-30659/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: ng:///AppModule/PhotoPage.ngfactory.js: Line 96 : ERROR CONTEXT
07-13 13:17:34.646 30659-30659/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(96)] "ERROR CONTEXT", source: ng:///AppModule/PhotoPage.ngfactory.js (96)

Comment: Ur application was working correctly without this plugin?

Comment: Yes no problem when I don't try to use this plugin.
(I answered below for add the screen of the error)

Comment: can you show your code where you calling the sms plugin?you can share it by any online IDE

Comment: @Nooby- you can refer this for refrence:https://github.com/abritopach/ionic-receiver-sms

Comment: I tried like this : https://ideone.com/YsAbiz and I have an html page wich call the function tryPlugin2().